# unsupported alpn protocol guzzle aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, composer-php, aws-lambda-layers

I'm running through this installation guide,

https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/tree/master/0.1-SimplePhpFunction

I have built PHP and am running PHP 7.3.0;

And now at the stage where I have installed Composer,

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | ./bin/php
```

So I have now installed Composer and am trying to install the guzzlehttp/guzzle;

I created a composer.json file which looks like this;

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
    }
}
```

However when I run the following line;

```
./bin/php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

I get this response;

```
ec2-user:~/environment/php-7-bin $ ./bin/php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle

In CurlDownloader.php line 365:
                                                                                                          
  curl error 0 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: unsupported ALPN protocol: ''  
                                                                                                          

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]

Segmentation fault
ec2-user:~/environment/php-7-bin $
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated thankyou.

Install guzzlehttp/guzzle.

Furthermore I have included this if its any help;

```
ec2-user:~/environment/php-7-bin $ ./bin/php -v
PHP 7.3.0 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2023 21:28:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
ec2-user:~/environment/php-7-bin $ ./bin/php -m | grep -i curl
curl
ec2-user:~/environment/php-7-bin $ ./bin/php -m | grep -i openssl
openssl
ec2-user:~/environment/php-7-bin $
```

Comment: Make sure that your curl and openssl versions are current, though you're building EOL PHP so YMMV depending on how close to "current" you can actually get.

Comment: Why do you try to run Composer on any other system than your local development machine? Also, keep in mind that PHP 7.3 is horribly outdated and should no longer be used in any kind of project, especially if you run 7.3.0 which isn't even the latest bugfix release from the 7.3 series